# Import XAML Canvas into Expression Design?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, expression-blend, expression-design

I have an XAML (Canvas/Path) icon I've been using in Expression Blend for a WPF 4 project.  I'd now like to use Expression Design to modify the icon, but I can find no way to open, import, or copy the icon into Expression Design.

I've found plenty of discussion of how to move images from Design to Blend, but not the other way around.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use Inkscape.

- http://inkscape.org/

It allows the loading of XAML files and you can Save As various different formats.

You can pick .emf (Enhanced Metafile format) as output...as it's one of the formats Expression Designer can read.

Note, the conversion may not be perfect...it depends on the support in each of the formats for representing the different elements and how closely they can be represented.

Have shown an example, where I started with some XAML in KAXAML....which I loaded in Inkscape....saved out as .emf, and then loaded in Expression Designer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Colin!  It looks like that would do the trick.  It's rather astonishing if Designer can't read in XAML images!